# C# Active Directory attribute Logon-Count reached maximum

Tags: c#, active-directory

For each user we're retrieving the logon count in Active Directory (through C#).
Now I've noticed that some users are all set to **65535**.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Due to compatibility with 16-bit versions of LAN Manager, the attribute has an upper limit of 65535. After this limit has been reached, you cannot use it as an indicator of user activity on this domain controller.

I'm just curious (it's not a big issue), is there another way to retieve the logon count from Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the counter to 0 if the limit has been reached.
simply set 
.Properties["logoncount"].Value = 0;
.CommitChanges();

You need the correct rights to update this info.

Comment: If we reset the logon count, we don't know how much a user has logged in anymore. I could, however, save how many times a reset has occured for the user and then calculate the logon count... however not really a nice solution.